# How do I get my Python date in the format that I want?

Tags: python, time, date-parsing, date-formatting

I'm reading a date from an Excel cell in Python (using `.Value` on the cell)... the result that I get is:

```
07/06/10 00:00:00
```

I thought this was a string, and so went about trying to figure out how to convert this to the format I need ("yyyyMMdd", or "20100706" in this example). However, after some playing around I realized that it is *not* being pulled as a string... Running type() on it returns `<type 'time'>` .

I then assumed that it was a Python time object, and tried using `strftime` on it to convert it to a string... but that didn't work either. It doesn't recognize the `strftime` method on the value.

Any idea on how to parse this properly and get the format I want? What am I doing wrong? (And if this clearly contains a date as well as a time, why is Python automatically considering it a time object?)

Comment: a cell in what? pygtk? tkinter? a random webpage?

Comment: what cell? Is this excel? or what?

Comment: oh whoops. sorry, my bad. yes, excel. I'll update the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert it to a time object like this:

```
import time
time.strptime(str(thetime), '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')
```

And then you should be able to manipulate it to your hearts content.

HTH

Comment: Tried that... I get `AttributeError: type object 'datetime.time' has no attribute 'strptime'`

Comment: I think that the `time` in `time.strptime()` is a module and not an object.

Comment: @Alex Bliskovsky - not sure I get it... how do I change the code to make it work?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention which module I was referring to. Fixed

Comment: @froadie: I suspect that you are importing `datetime.time` as `time` and not `time`. The former does not have a `strptime` attribute. Changing the import to `import time` should help.

Alternately you can do the following: `from datetime import datetime; datetime.strptime(str(cell.Value), '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')`

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I had a `from datetime import time` that was interfering. It's working now :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `str(time)`? That should give it to you in a string and then you can play around with the formatting all you like.